# Display many views efficiently in a FlexboxLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-flexboxlayout, layout-optimization

My goal is to efficiently display a lot of TextViews (with background) in a FlexboxLayout (or something similar).

I want to display information about actors and crew members from a movie in a kind of 'tag'-layout style

[How the layout looks like (one of the FlexboxLayouts is marked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTfuf.png)

I inflate the TextViews **dynamically** via LayoutInflater into a FlexboxLayout. The **problem** is of course that with **a lot of data (which means a lot of views**, sometimes 30 or more in over 20 Flexbox-Layouts) the creation time of my fragment/activity increases and the **activtiy takes longer to open**.

The TextView I inflate:

```
<TextView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/tag_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:paddingStart="10dp"
      android:paddingEnd="10dp"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_tag"
      android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary"
      android:text="@string/placeholder" />
```

My container layout (TextViews get inflated into the FlexboxLayout `@+id/fxl_names`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_names"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="test" />

  //TextViews get inflated into this FlexboxLayout

  <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/fxl_names"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view_more"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:text="Show all"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for any help/advice on optimizing this layout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you had to inflate a lot of views dynamically, you should use something called `ViewHolder` to ensure the optimization of the inflate view action.

For your problem may you had to use a `RecyclerView` instead a `FlexBoxLayout`, the best solution in my opinion. And a `FlexBoxLayoutManager` to organize your views.

There is a example in the [Android FlexBoxLayout repository](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview)

Comment: ViewHolders don't help with creation time, they help with recycling.  If anything, they (negligibly) slow down creation, because another object needs to be created.

Comment: I don't said that ViewHolders help with creation time, but the `RecyclerView` (my suggestion for the problem) is efficiently because the recycling action from use of ViewHolder.

Comment: Given that the problem is "the creation time of my fragment/activity increases and the activtiy takes longer to open", and especially given that the items are all onscreen at once, I don't think recycling will help here

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it actually improves the performance a lot. In my attached screenshot it is true that all child views from one FlexboxLayout are on screen as @RyanM pointed out (so I'm still dealing with a bit of delay, which is fine for me), but there are also a lot of views not visible on screen which could be recycled instead of added to an LinearLayout.